# Memory Leak in Jackson BufferRecycler

Tags: java, jackson, akka-http

My application is a web socket client that continuously parses JSon using Jackson 2.9.4.
I am experiencing a memory leak with SoftReferences in Thread Local not being cleared.

I have configured Jackson to NOT use a Thread Local as follows:

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
factory = factory.disable(JsonFactory.Feature.USE_THREAD_LOCAL_FOR_BUFFER_RECYCLING);
objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
```

But despite this setting, I keep seeing increases in char[] referenced by BufferRecycler:

[image]

This takes up around 40% of the physical memory and keeps growing, regardless of memory pressure, until I run out of physical memory.

1. How can I disable the use of Thread Local by Jackson?
2. What causes this BufferRecycler reference to be kept in memory?

Thanks,

Stik

Comment: if you could post the all around context for the mapper usage. Are you reopening the factory each time ? Is the converted object being directly flushed to some connector , or you simply keep it up in RAM ? Also you notice this behavior in both serialization and de-serialization and also for all type of messages ? Or you have a pretty-complex data model that keeps hard `Map<>` in it

Comment: I use a static Object Mapper, shared by all Threads (as suggested [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Presentation:-Jackson-Performance)), which is initialised with the factory shown above.
The converted object is a simple POJO (no complex Maps) and passed to a different server so not kept in memory.
Since I'm consuming a websocket, It's happening on de-serialization.

Comment: hmm cannot be sure but it could also mean that AKKA is keeping the `Byte[]` due to the web socket sessions. Have you tried terminating the Web Sockets sessions ? If you close the channel , is the stream still kept in RAM?

Comment: I did think about that and build in a hard disconnect every hour but this had no impact on the leak. It looks like the only reference is the soft reference but I don't understand why it's not being GCd

Comment: is it hard to change the layer that you do the de-serialization ? Try changing it with a simple Jersey Client and also make it Stateless , do not reuse the client instance